# How can i stop sounds from soundpool on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to create a soundboard and I am stuck since its the first time working on action bar.
So I have created the menu and the button is shown on the action bar and its shown to the activities I want but I don't know how to make it so when pressed to stop all the sounds from sound pool.
When I try creating a `SoundPool.stop()` I get"  (Non-static method 'stop(int)' cannot be referenced from a static context"(im probably doing it wrong but i dont know how to do it). I would really appreciate it if someone could help since I've been trying to learn about it and I cant seem to find anything close to it.

Here's the code:

```
   import android.media.AudioManager;
   import android.media.SoundPool;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;



   public class soundMainjava extends AppCompatActivity {

    SoundPool mySound;
    int sound1Id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.soundMain);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mySound = new SoundPool(99, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        sound1Id = mySound.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
    }

    public void pb1(View view) {
        mySound.play(sound1Id, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    }

    //inflates the menu;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the menu code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 tools:context="com.example.---.testsounds.soundMainjava">
 <item
     android:id="@+id/action_sound"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_volume_off_black_24dp"
     android:title=""
     app:showAsAction="always"/>
 </menu>
```

here is the code that doesn't work:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_sound:
            SoundPool.stop(sound1Id);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Comment: Add error description to the question.

Comment: okay done i added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is :

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_sound:
// You are calling the static method.
            SoundPool.stop(sound1Id);
// You have to call the object created from SoundPool Class
            return true;`
```

So this should be

```
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_sound:
            mySound.stop(sound1Id);
            return true;
```

Here is a fully working sample :

```
     public class SoundPlayer {

    private static final float leftVol = 1.0f;
    private static final float rightVol = 1.0f;
    private static final float rate = 1.0f;
    private static final int loop = 0;
    private static final int priority = 1;
    private static SoundPool soundPool;

    private static int startListeningSound;
    private static int stopListeningSound;

      public SoundPlayer(Context context) {
        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(2).build();

        startListeningSound = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.google_now_tone, priority);
        stopListeningSound = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.google_glass_done, priority);

}
        public void playStartVoiceSound() {
        soundPool.play(startListeningSound, leftVol, rightVol, priority, loop, rate);
    }

       public void playStopVoiceSound() {
        soundPool.play(stopListeningSound, leftVol, rightVol, priority, loop, rate);
    }
```

And when calling in your activity :

```
    private SoundPlayer soundPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...
        soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(this);
    ...
    //   calling soundPlayer to play the sound :
    int streamId =  soundPlayer.playStartVoiceSound();


    // calling the soundPlayer stop 

     soundPlayer.stop(streamId);
     }
```